# How can I set f.select field as required - rails 5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I set f.select field as required?

`:required => true` isn't working

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Bedrooms</label>
<%= f.select :bed_room, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3",3], ["4",4], ["5",5], ["6",6], ["7",7], ["8",8], ["9",9], ["10+",10]], prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", :required => true  %>
</div>
```

Tks in advance

Comment: Try using `{:required => true}` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm:

```
<%= f.select :bed_room, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3",3], ["4",4], ["5",5], ["6",6], ["7",7], ["8",8], ["9",9], ["10+",10]], { prompt: "Select..." }, { class: "form-control", required: true } %>
```